# Android RTP SDP X264 problem (Have audio, but no Video)

Tags: android, h.264, rtp, sdp

Android will play both the audio and video (AAC,h263) that I server it from my rtp server, but when I serve an AAC/H264 stream, I only get the audio and no video.

In the working scenario, Android issues a SETUP command for both track ids, but the H264, android never issues the SETUP command for the second Video track.

Is my SDP file correct? The profile-id and sprops I believe are correct as are copied directly from the sps and pps NALs from the H264 encoder. The video is baseline@2.1

Is Android failing to repsond or recognise the second track?

If I stream the video file by itself with live555 it works fine, and I have compared the SDP file it produces with my own one.

Any ideas? 
Thanks

H264/AAC SDP file:

```
v=0
o=xxx IN IP4 192.168.13.43
s=live.3gp
u=http:///
e=admin@
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:187
t=0 0
a=control:rtsp://192.168.13.43:555/live.3gp
a=isma-compliance:1,1.0,1
a=range:npt=0-  2630.336000
m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 97
a=rtpmap:97 MP4A-LATM/44100/2
a=control:rtsp://192.168.13.43:555/live.3gp/trackID=1
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=41; cpresent=0; config=400024203fc0
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=control:rtsp://192.168.13.43:555/live.3gp/trackID=2
a=cliprect:0,0,256,432
a=framesize:96 432-256
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; profile-level-id=42C015;sprop-parameter-   sets=Njc0MkMwMTVGNDBEODQzNjAyMjAwMDAwMDMwMDIwMDAwMDAzMDNDMUUzMDY1NA==,NjhDRTA0NzI=
```

SDP file produced by live555 for the same video file which does display on Android:

```
v=0
o=- 1303401850159891 1 IN IP4 192.168.13.58
s=H.264 Video, streamed by the LIVE555 Media Server
i=live.3g
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.01.19
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:H.264 Video, streamed by the LIVE555 Media Server
a=x-qt-text-inf:baseCasterCap.264
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:500
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42C015;sprop-parameter-sets=Z0LAFfQNhDYCIAAAAwAgAAADA8HjBlQ=,aM4Ecg==
a=control:track1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help Jesup, it was very much appreciated.

The problem was the sprop parameters, I noticed when I copy and pasted the second SDP file for you.

The encoder I used to do the base64 calculation for my testing was for character data, not binary data. So 65 was being interpreted as the character 6, and the character 5, and encoded, rather than the single number (A in ascii I guess). 
Does that make sense?
Silly mistake on my part. Thanks again
Ian

Answer (score 1):

sprop-parameter-sets shouldn't have a tab or space in it (may be a copy/paste bug).

Android (or the player being used there) may not support packetization-mode 1.  0 is required; 1 is optional.

a=framesize and a=cliprect - those aren't standard H.264, but may not be a problem.

I assume the port 0 is normal for your usage (since audio works)?  In offer-answer, port 0 would be a rejected stream (in an answer; in an offer it means a disabled stream).

I've seen implementations (I'm looking at YOU, Grandstream!) that insist on spaces after semi-colons for H264 fmtp (they're wrong) - you have a mixture.

Is the "C0" in the profile-level-id correct?  that adds constraints; try it without the constraints and see what the response is.  (You can still send a more-constrained stream than the SDP indicated.)

Comment: Hi Jesup, Thank you for your reply! The sprop space was indeed a copy and paste bug. I removed the "a=framesize and a=cliprect" and tried differing packetisation modes,but without success. I also adjusted the spaces in the h264 fmt line as you suggested, but again without any luck.And also as you said,I changed the C0 for profile-iop to 80 (which according to the spec indicates the baseline contraints),but I still have no video.The same file will stream correctly with live555,and I have attempted to copy that sdp file as much as possible. Do you think it might not be related to the sdp file?

Comment: The only thing that makes me think it is related is that the file will stream correctly with live555. Thanks

Comment: Nothing guarantees that live555 follows the spec (or that the android player follows the spec).  As mentioned before, port 0 is very suspicious to me, but may be ok since audio works.  Do you have an example that *does* work with this player to compare?  Also - strip it to the bare minimum.  In addition check the resolution and other PPS/SPS values and make sure the player will render video with those.  It might not "like" something about the stream.  (That would be non-compliant, but not one enforces this, and resolution in particular is a thorny issue.) And does the player support level 2.1?

Comment: The same h264 video file (just the raw vid, no audio) with live555 produces the following SDP file (note the same port:0, in my server the ports are created when SETUP is revieved for the track).  It displasy correctly on the android phone. Android supports baseline level 3 (i presume that means "up to"), but the video decodes perfectly with live555. I'll try and strip it to a minimum and see what happens. I will double check the SPS/PPS, but I am sure they comform - android supports 30fps and 480 x 360 px - but again my params are the same as used by live555 which does work. It's bizarre!

Comment: I added the working SDP file from live555 to the original question, it doesnt display very nicely here in the comments! :) Thanks

Comment: ok, i just noticed different sprops, let me verify the live555 sdp file first